# Marshal not serializing or deserializing nested serialized attributes properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This is kind of a tough problem to explain, because I don't really know what is going on. I've made a repository with instructions of how to reproduce:

https://github.com/bricker/cache_nested_serialized_attributes

Basically:

- User has_many Posts
- Post has serialized attribute :metadata

And to reproduce:

```
users = User.first(2)
users.first.posts.first
users.last.posts.first
dump = Marshal.dump(users)
Marshal.load(dump)
=> [#<User id: 1, name: "bricker", created_at: "2013-04-24 06:26:03", updated_at: "2013-04-24 06:26:03">, 
    :@new_record]
```

You can see the unexpected output in that final line. It only seems to occur under those specific conditions. Just calling `users.first.posts` works fine. Not calling `.posts` at all works fine. It's only when I load a specific post from a user before dumping that this happens.

The main difference I notice between Rails 4 (which works properly) and Rails 3.2.13 (which doesn't work) is that when calling `Marshal.dump(users)` in Rails 3, the Posts are reloaded:

```
dump = Marshal.dump(users)
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."user_id" = 1
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."user_id" = 2
```

... which doesn't happen in Rails 4.

I wish I could explain better but it's such an obscure problem. Please ask questions if you need clarification, and look at or clone the repo.

This is tested and confirmed on a vanilla Rails 3.2.13 (see repository). This behavior does *not* happen in Rails 4.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems you're not alone having problems with marshalling AR objects : https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2431 . This ticket is old, and `_load` and `_dump` may have changed since - unfortunately I can't find these methods in rails source. In my opinion you should try to find the methods in the source to see if there's a problem, and / or file an issue in rails official tracker - looks like a rails bug to me !

Comment: Thanks - `_load` and `_dump` (and similar methods `marshal_load` and `marshal_dump`) are Ruby core methods. I think this is a Rails problem because of the fact that it doesn't happen in Rails 4, but it does in Rails 3.2.

Comment: yes, they are core methods, but in this issue you can see that the rails team overrided them. I think the reason it works in rails 4 and not in 3.2 is that the methods overrides have changed inbetween version - so spot the methods in the two versions, see the difference, and maybe patch your own classes... note: my bad, you're dumping Relations, not AR::Base objects - but i think the same "bug-chase strategy" is still relevant

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed on Rails master, and a [simple patch](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9705) is pending review on 3-2-stable. I've applied the patch manually in an initializer and it fixes the problem.

See here for the patch: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10322#issuecomment-16913855